# Map is not able to load in the view

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps

I am doing programming in codeigniter + ajax + javascript and I have to fetch the longitude and latitude based on the user's entry in textbox.

I am already get the right response from the controller but view is not able to convert those longitude and latitude into maps even maps are not load on the page.

Here you can see my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     function submitMe(selector)
   {
       //alert(selector);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/locationcontroller/getLocation",
       data: {location:selector },
       success:function(longitude){
//           alert(selector);
        locate=longitude.split(" ");
        latlong(locate[0],locate[1],selector);
       
    }
   
});
}
 
 $('#address').blur(function(){
 var add=$('#address').val();
// alert(add);
       submitMe(add);
 });
 
 
});
function latlong(lat,long,selector)
 {
     
     alert(lat);
     alert(long);
     var selector=selector;
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
     var map;
var marker;
 
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function initialize(){
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 18,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
 
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), mapOptions);
 
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: myLatlng,
draggable: true
});
 
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatlng }, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
if (results[0]) {
$('#latitude,#longitude').show();
selector=results[0].formatted_address;
$('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
$('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
}
});
 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
 
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
if (results[0]) {
selector=results[0].formatted_address;
$('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
$('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
}
});
});
 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
     
 }
```

```css
#myMap {
   height: 350px;
   width: 680px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<form method="POST">
            <div id="myMap"></div>
<!--<input id="" type="text" style="width:600px;"/><br/>-->
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
<input type="text" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude"/>
<input type="text" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```

- [code of view](http://pastebin.com/GgqJUF8P)
- [code of the controller](http://pastebin.com/BYygqmxL)

Comment: Please include  your code inside the post instead of links, and specify what the problem is and where it occurs.

Comment: @DanielB codes are too long should i still add them in the posts?

Comment: You should add the relevant code. You state that the view is unable to do something, so why include the controller code? If the problem is in the view, include that and specify what does not work.

Comment: add relevant part of the code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your javascript to

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function submitMe(selector) {
        //alert(selector);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/locationcontroller/getLocation",
            data: { location: selector },
            //success: function (longitude) {
            error: function (longitude) { // error because jsfiddle doesn't support ajax
                //alert(selector);
                longitude = "1.0001203013 12.0000001";
                locate = longitude.split(" ");
                latlong(locate[0], locate[1]);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#address').blur(function () {
        var add = $('#address').val();
        // alert(add);
        submitMe(add);
    });


});

function latlong(lat, long) {

    alert(lat);
    alert(long);
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    initialize(myLatlng);

}

// RELEVANT CHANGE: move initialize function outside of latlng, and receives the coordinates as parameter.

function initialize(myLatlng) {

    var map;
    var marker;

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: myLatlng,
        draggable: true
    });

    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': myLatlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                $('#latitude,#longitude').show();
                selector = results[0].formatted_address;
                $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {

        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    selector = results[0].formatted_address;
                    $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                    $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            }
        });
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
  // RELEVANT CHANGE: initialize function receives an initial value.
   var initialLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.55555, 10.55555);
   initialize(initialLatlng);
});
```

```css
#myMap {
   height: 350px;
   width: 680px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<form method="POST">
    <div id="myMap"></div>
    <!--<input id="" type="text" style="width:600px;"/><br/>-->
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
    <input type="text" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude"/>
    <input type="text" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**Relevant changes**

- move initialize function outside of latlng, and now receives the
  coordinates as parameter.
- initialize function receives an initial value

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/qv6v57L1/)

Comment: I AM MAKING A CODE IN WHICH USER ENTER THE LOCATION OR PINCODE & ACCORDING TO IT MAP WILL BE LOADED BUT MAP SHOULD BE LOAD BEFORE THE SUBMIT BUTTON,HERE I AM USING BLUR FUNCTION SO AS USER WILL OUT FROM THE ADDRESS TEXTBOOX MAP SHOULD BE LOADED,LET ME TRY YOUR CODE.

Comment: WHEN I ENTER THE PINCODE ,LON & LAT WILL BE CALCULATED BY ENTERED PINCODE.